# php / mysql select- this is an easy one

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, select, resultset

I have this code.

```
 <?php
        require('connection/conn.php');
        mysql_select_db($db_name,$ligação);
        //$rsArticle = mysql_query("CALL get_article(1,518)");
        $rsArticle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblarticles WHERE ArticleID = 518");
        while($rowArticle = mysql_fetch_array($rsArticle)){
            echo $rowArticle;
        }
    ?>
```

And instead of getting the text that exists in the database I just get the word: Array

The line that is commented its for calling a stored procedure. In a desperate measure I made a simple select, in the next line

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: print_r($rowArticle) and you'll see what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the word Array is because what you are echoing is an Array.  Use something like echo $rowArticle['column-name']; to echo the data from a specific column of your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can't echo an array. try print_r() instead

if you want the values individually, do something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsArticle, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    //echo the first column of the record (index 0)
    echo $row[0];
}
```

look in the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for more info

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array with elements for every field in your database table.

Either print the whole array with `print_r()` or use `echo $rowArticle[COLOUMN_NAME]` to echo certain values from your resultset.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() returns you the array, when you use echo is actually return the object type in case of array.

use print_r($rowArticle); instead of echo.